# Attribute error using Jinja2 grouby filter

Tags: python, filter, group-by, jinja2

Trying to get the groupby filter to work I'm getting an Atribute error. My groupby code looks like:

```
{% for year, year_purchases in purchases|groupby('PurchaseDate.year')|reverse %}
            <h2 class="year">{{ year }}</h2>
            {% for ... %}
            {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where purchases is a list of PurchaseEntity:

```
class PurchaseEntity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.PurchaseDate = ''
        self.Orders = []

    def load_from_query(self,result):
        self.PurchaseDate = result.PurchaseDate
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: PurchaseEntity instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The problem seems to be in environment.py:

```
def getitem(self, obj, argument):
"""Get an item or attribute of an object but prefer the item."""
try:
    return obj[argument]
except (TypeError, LookupError): #<-- Here it raises the error
    if isinstance(argument, basestring): #<-- It never reaches here
        try:
            attr = str(argument)
        except Exception:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                return getattr(obj, attr)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    return self.undefined(obj=obj, name=argument)
```

I don't think that its a Jinja2 or "groupby" error, because the getitem funcion is used everywhere. I googled it and couldn't fint anything related. However, what I did is change the "except (TypeError, LookupError):" line and It worked with any this alternatives:

```
except:
except Exception:
```

I don't know if my class delcaration is wrong or if I'm just missing something, because I tried with other clases (created by SQLAlchemy with autoload) and it worked fine. Any suggestions?

Btw, the arguments sent to getitem are:

```
>>> (obj,argument)
(<project.logic.purchase.PurchaseEntity instance at 0x050DF148>, 'PurchaseDate')
>>> obj.PurchaseDate
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 25, 17, 1, 44)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making PurchaseEntity extend object:

```
class PurchaseEntity(object):
```

Basic classes that do not extend anything throw an AttributeError when you try to lookup an item and they do not have it. Objects throw TypeError.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self):
...             void    
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def bar(self):
...             void
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> foo['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> bar['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it worked flawlessly! Could you tell me what's the difference between both? Besides the fact that one works and the other doesn't :) Should I always inherit from the "object" type/class/?.

Comment: The object class was added in python 2.2. In python 3 everything inherits from the `object` class. I always inherit from it. The main difference with the object class is that all attributes that are added to the object are stored in the self.__dict__ dictionary. Take a look at http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/ for more info.

Comment: shouldn't you receive `TypeError: 'Bar' object is not subscriptable` instead?