# Python - Count on a generator (Jinja2)

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to make statistics based on data in one line. I'm used to use underscore.js in JS, but I want to do that in Python, using Jinja2.

`data` is an array that contains `players` that contains `villages` which is an array too and contains stuff like `points`.

Screenshot of the `data`:

[image]

For the moment I want to know how many villages there are in the data, for all players.

I tried this:
`{{ data|map(attribute='villages')|count }}`

But I get this error: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

I've started python today so...

Comment: `map` returns a generator. generators are structures that provide items one at a time (similar to Java Iterator), which means that you can't know their size a priori. You need to create a list from it first. probably something like `{{ data|map(attribute='villages')|list|count }}`

Comment: I get `AttributeError: Player instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: seems like a different issue. you need to post a complete trace of the error.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738338/attribute-error-using-jinja2-grouby-filter Make Player extend `object` (new object style, contains the `__getitem__` method)

Comment: I've tried for several hours now, many things, nothing works correctly and it's really hard to understand where I am in the loops. Ruby and JS are much better languages to deal with this kind of stuff. I'll try your solution later @njzk2, thanks.

Comment: the definition of your Player class must start with `class Player(object)`. I did not really enjoyed jinja either, and tend to stick with json services on the python side and js on client side to put data in shape.